# Databasequery for retrieval

Tags: android, database

I have the following query to retrieve data from a database.

But it is always returning as 0.

Please help me.

My query:

```
   System.out.println("passed="+grp);
    long sum=0;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
                 "SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE category='Income' AND groups='grp'",null);
         if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
         {
           sum = cursor1.getLong(0);
         }
         cursor1.close();
         String housetotal=String.valueOf((long)sum);       
         System.out.println("house="+housetotal);
             return housetotal;
```

I checked the database there are 2 entries that are satisfying the above condition.

However, it is always returning as 0.

Comment: print `sum` on console and check you are really getting value or not.

Comment: System.out.println("sum="+sum);  it is coming as 0..IS there any wrong in the query???

Comment: Print query on console and check.\

Comment: How can i print query in consloe.Whether by using log.v??

Comment: My dear, the best suggestion i would suggest you is that **Go and Get a good book for learning Android app development**.

Comment: Thanks  Paresh Mayani..surely i will do that....

Answer (score 1):

For String, USE LIKE, NOT = and, in SQLITE, use " not ' :

```
"SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE category LIKE \"Income\" AND groups LIKE \"grp\""
```